# How to take an intermediate data for the complex sql query. Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join

I have some complex queries to the postgresql which takes data from several tables joined each other with outer left join operators.

I need to test these queries so I need a fixtures for the tests contain only data I need, not whole tables data.

How could I see the intermediate results for these join subqueries to use it as a fixtures?

For example, I have tables A, B and C and query

```
SELECT A.column 
FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN B ON A.b_id = B.id 
  LEFT JOIN C ON A.c_id = C.a_id
```

How could I take a result as "From table a: {part of A table taking part on query}, From table B {part of B table taking part on query}" etc, when parts of tables shows needed data or something like this. Is there any existing tool or method for it?

Unfortunately, EXPLAIN and ANALYSE shows only statistics and benchmarks, not data.

Comment: That'd be a nice thing to have, but in PostgreSQL your best bet is probably to execute a partial query to get intermediate results.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly you're looking for a way to get the product of `A left join B on  A.b_id = B.id`, but without having to edit the query. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you mean

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN B ON A.b_id = B.id 
  LEFT JOIN C ON A.c_id = C.a_id
limit 10
```

to see what's happening in A from the join?

Or perhaps

```
select concat('from table a', a.col1, a.col2...) ,
concat('from table b', b.col1, b.col2...) 
from ...
```

String functions such as concat: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

also worth looking into http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html at array_append()

Comment: No. I'm looking for a tool like Explain Query in PgAdminIII or something like this. Maybe a console command or something else to automate the process

Comment: @AlexeyProtchenko: the "explain query" output from pgAdmin just uses the output from a native `explain` statement. So if the information you are looking for is in the (graphical) execution plan show in pgAdmin, then it's also in the output of `explain` or `explain (analyze, verbose)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I mean that I need a tool like Explain Query which should show intermediate data from tables, not a bencmarks

Comment: @AlexeyProtchenko: sorry I don't get it. The data that pgAdmin's explain plan shows **is** available in the output of the `explain` command. What **exactly** does pgAdmin's explain plan output show you that you can't find in the output of a "regular" `explain`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. No, I can't find needed functional neither pgAdmin's explain nor simple console EXPLAIN ANALYSE. I need an intermediate data in each step of query performance. Like a part of a B table data used for join to the A, not the whole B table data

Comment: @AlexeyProtchenko: so what exactly then do you mean with "pgAdmin's explain query"? Which menu item do you use to invoke that?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name, I mean that I need the similar interface with other functionality or just a couple of commands to see the intermediate tables data

Comment: @AlexeyProtchenko, you can either use explain to see HOW the query works, or SELECT to see the DATA the query selects. What you want is not a supported functionality of postgres, to give you intermediate results for a query. You would have to do that yourself by selecting parts of the data and looking at it, or find a client/app that will issue smaller queries for you. You sound like you already have something in mind, perhaps you used a tool before with another RDBMS?

Comment: @AdrianBR, my team lead told me about the same tool for MsSQLServer

Comment: @AlexeyProtchenko perhaps this will answer your question. Remember to search by the keywords you have, your TL probably mentioned a ms sql workbench. You should defintiely ask him for more detail and go from there.